# Will toluene vapors damage a mirror made from PETG?

Tags: polymers, solvents, plastics

I'm working on a project for work and trying to avoid using an acrylic mirror because I know that doesn't hold up well against toluene, but I'm wondering if a mirror made out of PETG would?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PETG is also not resistant against toluene.
A month-long contact under ambient conditions results a complete swollen/disintegrated PETG material (PDL rating 0), and an year-long exposure even causes whitening [1, p. 2660]:

> [image: PETG datasheet]

#### References

1. *Chemical Resistance of Thermoplastics*; Woishnis, W. A., Ebnesajjad, S., Eds.; PDL handbook series; William Andrew: Norwich, N.Y, **2012**. ISBN 978-1-4557-7896-6.

Comment: Thanks, have you yourself ever heard of a plastic that's actually resistant to toluene that can be used for a mirror? I'm having trouble finding anything, I mostly see Teflon and Nylon..

Comment: @Zayas12 From the top of my head, not really, sorry.